# create arrays from elements of another array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a array called array3;

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Commercial
    [1] => Infrastructure
)
```

I want to iterate thtough each element of this array and create individual arrays based on the values. I have tried this;

```
$array4 = array();
$array5= array();
foreach ($array3 as $value) {
  $array4[] = array('v' => count(search($rows, 'domaindesc', $value)));
  $array4[] = array('v' => $value);
  $array5[] = array('c' => $array4);

}
```

the search function is returning the no of maching elements  from another array. The output I get from the above code is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [c] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [v] => 5
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [v] => Commercial
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [c] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [v] => 5
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [v] => Commercial
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [v] => 1
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [v] => Infrastructure
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

What I am trying to get is;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [c] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [v] => 5
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [v] => Commercial
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [c] => Array
                (                    

                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [v] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [v] => Infrastructure
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: do your self a favour use array names that mean something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each iteration, you are adding onto $array4 and putting that into $array5

Try re-declaring $array4 each iteration:

```
$array5 = array();
foreach ($array3 as $value) {
  $array4 = array();
  $array4[] = array('v' => count(search($rows, 'domaindesc', $value)));
  $array4[] = array('v' => $value);
  $array5[] = array('c' => $array4);

}
```

EDIT: For style, I would personally have written it as such:

```
$array5 = array();
foreach ($array3 as $value) {
    $array5[] = array('c' => array(
        array('v' => count(search($rows, 'domaindesc', $value))),
        array('v' => $value),
    ));
}
```

Note the trailing comma in the array declaration is intentional, making it easier for other devs to add more items to the declaration if needed. PHP allows this and I take advantage of it.

EDIT2: If you are not concerned about your PHP code not working on versions of PHP prior to 5.4, I prefer to use square brackets to declare an array instead of array(). It ends up looking even cleaner:

```
$array5 = [];
foreach ($array3 as $value) {
    $array5[] = ['c' => [
        ['v' => count(search($rows, 'domaindesc', $value))],
        ['v' => $value],
    ]];
}
```